# Does it make sense to create a Facebook account so I can tell them not to track me?

Tags: privacy, facebook, whatsapp

Not sure this is the right site to ask this, but here it goes.

I've never created a Facebook account, because I don't want people to know about me more than I know about them. But I do have an WhatsApp account (since before it was bought), it's practically a requirement where I live (not EU, unfortunately). I've taken every chance I have to opt out of data sharing, but now they've [changed the EULA](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2021/01/whatsapp-users-must-share-their-data-with-facebook-or-stop-using-the-app/) so you have to agree to share your data to continue using the app.

I've researched the privacy settings on Facebook and it seems that if I go to the trouble I can make an account that shares no data with anyone ("friends", advertisers, etc). So I'm considering creating an account just so I can reach the privacy settings and tell them not to use my data. I suppose they wouldn't know more about me than now; after all, they do have my shadow profile already.

The question is: Would that make me more private than just continue using WhatsApp without a Facebook account?

Comment: We cant answer this,what Facebook can and does with your data is up to them and whatever regulations imposed on them.Read the fine print and cross your fingers.

Comment: Facebook has already created a shadow account, don't worry. https://www.theverge.com/2018/4/11/17225482/facebook-shadow-profiles-zuckerberg-congress-data-privacy

Comment: If you used your main phone number to create your WhatsApp account, Facebook probably knows who you are, and who your friends and associates are, and quite possibly has also obtained more data about you from external data sources. Be aware that "an account that shares no data with anyone" is impossible: Facebook has the all the data, and can use it for almost any purpose not explicitly forbidden in the terms of service in force at the moment (subject to change).